# Match line that doesn't end with >\s* using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, ant

Can we match a line using regular expression that doesn't end with pattern -

```
>\s*
```

In other words, **>\s*$** matches those lines that ends with **>** followed by zero or more space. I want to find those line that doesn't match it.

I'll use it to remove some line during ANT build.

**Solution**
^(?!.*>\s*$).* Provided by zx81

**Added :** 
Basically I'm trying to remove songle line comment during build.

```
(?<!http:|https:)\/\/.*$
```

Above regex is able to do that (I am considering there is no comment within quotetion mark). But I don't want to capture -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> - No match
<% // END: Modified %> - No match
```

**Example**

```
http://example.com - No match
abc  //  qqqqqqqqqq - Match
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> - No Match
// comment - Match
/* comment */ program //comment - Match
var ok = "not really"; - No Match
<% // END: Modified %> - No match
```

That was my some purpose. I'm sorry I am adding this condition after asking my original question. Can you guys help me for this as well.

Based on the solution provided by zx81 - below regex is working -

```
^(?!<!DOCTYPE[^>]*>\s*$)(?!<%[^>]*%>\s*$).*(?<!http:|https:)\/\/.*$
```

But it is matching the whole line. But I only want to capture string after //

However my original question is already answered and I've accepted the answer.

Comment: In .NET `^.*(?<!>\s*)$` would suffice, which is the trivial way of approaching this, but sadly nearly no other engine allows arbitrary-length lookbehind ...

Comment: Yeah, I've tested your soution in http://www.rubular.com/. It's showing invalid pattern in look-behind :(

Comment: that's why it's always useful to specify the regex flavour you are using.

Comment: @Kartic he means `.NET`. `.NET` lookbehind allows that.

Comment: @zespri: Last I checked, Ant was Java. I'll throw in those tags in the hopes they are correct. Most of the online regex testing tools use either Flash or JavaScript, so they are useless regarding the more advanced features anyway.

Comment: @Јοеу, yep, good deduction, thank you for your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in multi-line mode (`m` flag in non-Ruby flavor):

```
^(?!.*>\s*$).*
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/51)

To set the `m` flag, depending on flavor: `(?m)^(?!.*>\s*$).*` or `/^(?!.*>\s*$).*/m`

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string
- The negative lookahead `(?!.*>\s*$)` asserts that what follows is not any chars then `>`, optional spaces and the end of the line
- `.*` matches the line

**Option 2 for Edited question**

Same idea, two lookarounds.

```
^(?!<!DOCTYPE[^>]*>\s*$)(?!<%[^>]*%>\s*$).*
```

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: This solution looks good. I'll update after one round of testing.

Comment: FYI, tweaked the answer and added demo, explanation and reference. :)

Comment: @zx81 I've chanded my question a bit. Can you please help me.

Comment: Are you saying that `<% // END: Modified %>` should be allowed to match?

Comment: No, I don't want to match a comment that ends with > followed by zero or more space.

Comment: Done, look at Option 2 at the bottom. :)

Comment: But it's capturing even if it doesnt have // and http://example.com as well. I want to capture string after // (including //) and if it doesn't end or start with > and it is not a part of URL

Comment: `(?m)` to set the flag should work in every implementation, regardless how options are usually given (whether as additional parameter or as suffixes to a regex literal).

Comment: @Joey But not in Ruby ([see this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#modifiers)) where `(?m)` is the equivalent of `(?s)` (DOTALL) elsewhere. At first the question was not tagged Java, that's why I mentioned it.